# Applescript check url to verify email address

Tags: javascript, applescript

Does anybody know the apple script to complete the following .

> check for new email from specific user
>   click on the url in the content

So for example, if john@appleseed.com emailed me with a link to his new website it would automatically open it in safari

Comment: You want to run this script every time you get new mail, or manually for current open mail?

Comment: you can do this with a mail rule, you need to parse the body of the mail if the body contains more content than the URL

Comment: Yeah, but every time you receive mail? Then it'll be annoying, you might be working on something and new mail shifts focus to Safari. Also may I ask why you want to do such thing?

Comment: just working on a solution for this, will have it sorted shortly.